# Flutter: navigate to another screen from inside of StreamBuilder builder callback

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

I have a splash screen and a `StreamBuilder` that emits a state that contains information about authentication status. When the authentication status is known, I want to navigate either to sign in page or home page. But when I write something like `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(...)` I get

> I/flutter ( 2058): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter ( 2058): The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder(dirty, state:
>   I/flutter ( 2058): _StreamBuilderBaseState>#f4346):
>   I/flutter ( 2058): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
>   I/flutter ( 2058): This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the
>   I/flutter ( 2058): process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase
>   I/flutter ( 2058): only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework
>   I/flutter ( 2058): builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built.
>   I/flutter ( 2058): Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
>   I/flutter ( 2058): The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
>   I/flutter ( 2058):   Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey#e0460](state: OverlayState#ab1a5(entries:
>   I/flutter ( 2058):   [OverlayEntry#4e962(opaque: false; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#7656a(opaque: false;
>   I/flutter ( 2058):   maintainState: true), OverlayEntry#1f86e(opaque: false; maintainState: false),
>   I/flutter ( 2058):   OverlayEntry#05a15(opaque: false; maintainState: true)]))
>   I/flutter ( 2058): The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
>   I/flutter ( 2058):   StreamBuilder(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState>#f4346)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): 
>   I/flutter ( 2058): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #0      Element.markNeedsBuild. (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3503:11)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3529:6)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1133:14)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #3      OverlayState.insertAll (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:346:5)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #4      OverlayRoute.install (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:43:24)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #5      TransitionRoute.install (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:180:11)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #6      ModalRoute.install (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:895:11)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #7      NavigatorState.pushReplacement (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1799:14)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #8      _replace (package:map_chat/application/navigation.dart:75:27)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #9      _SignInPage.replace (package:map_chat/application/navigation.dart:67:5)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #10     Roadmap.replace (package:map_chat/application/navigation.dart:25:18)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #11     _SplashPageState._buildPageBasedOnAuthenticationState (package:map_chat/feature/splash.dart:52:19)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #12     _SplashPageState._buildSplashScreen (package:map_chat/feature/splash.dart:40:11)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #13     _SplashPageState._buildPage. (package:map_chat/feature/splash.dart:27:18)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #14     StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:425:74)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #15     _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:125:48)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #16     StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3825:27)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #17     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3739:15)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #18     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3565:5)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #19     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2278:33)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #20     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:700:20)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #21     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:286:5)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #22     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1012:15)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #23     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:952:9)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #24     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame. (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:773:7)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #33     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #34     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): #35     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:171:12)
>   I/flutter ( 2058): (elided 8 frames from package dart:async and package dart:async-patch)

The only workaround I found is to schedule the navigation to the end of event queue using `Future(...).then(navigate)` but that's sick. Is here an adequate solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can listen your stream outside of build method and redirect to another view from there.

---- EDITED ----

This is an example of how you can do that:

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, _verify);
}

void _verify() {
    final _myBloc = BlocProvider.getBloc<MyBloc>();

    _myBloc.myStream.listen((data) {
        // Redirect to another view, given your condition
        if (data) { 
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("my-new-route");
        }
    });
}
```

Just remember to save the `StreamSubscription` object returned from `listen` method, so you can cancel the subscription on `dispose()`.

Comment: Yep that certainly makes more sense in my case. Just have figured out that I can just create a stream subscription inside a `Consumer` widget and dispose it in appropriate time

Comment: Your answer isn't complete, It would be better if you provided an example!

Answer (score 1):

I still not happy with my solution, but I use a

```
if(snapshot.hasdata && snapshot.data.navigate) {
     Future.microtask(() => Navigator.of(context).push... );
   }
```